# Почему нельзя подключать файлы напрямую?

Tags: c++

Почему в c++ нельзя сразу подключать в includ'е .cpp файлы а нужно создавать файл заголовков? Правильно ли я понимаю что прототипы функций с помощью линкера имеют возможность получать доступ к их реализации в другом(.cpp) файле? Так же был бы рад если бы объяснили как конкретно (в той же  VS) дать файлы для связывания линкеру? На сколько я понял там надо что то в сборщике прописывать, но для меня эта тема пока что темный лес(Хотелось бы знать хотя бы базовую информацию чтобы иметь общее представление).

Answer (score 2):

Что значит "нельзя"? Подключать через `#include` вы можете что угодно, куда угодно и сколько угодно. Но при этом надо следить за тем, чтобы результат такого подключения не нарушал правил языка. Никто вам не запрещает писать программы, представляющие собой один здоровенный файл, собранный при помощи `#include`, если вы делаете все правильно.

Другое дело, что написание мало-мальски серьезной программы по принципу "один здоровенный файл" будет очень нерациональным занятием из-за того, что каждая мелкая модификация будет требовать перекомпиляции всей программы. В первую очередь именно поэтому программу обычно разбивают на набор более мелких независимых файлов, компилируемых по отдельности. А там уже и возникает условное деление на заголовочные файлы, файлы реализации и т.п. Деление на более крупные модели - библиотеки, в т.ч. динамические - фактически в многом преследует те же цели.

Как "дать файлы для связывания линкеру" зависит от того, в какой среде разработки вы работаете. В Visual Studio вы обычно работаете с проектами в составе решения (solution). Ваша задача - добавлять файлы в проект, а уж к линкеру они сами попадут. Ничего нигде прописывать не нужно.